# Adding join or explict join

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope is all well. I am encountering an issue writing SQL query. I did it successfully, however, now I am trying to add explicit JOIN in the query but cant seem to get it or do it properly. Any pointers or tips would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

```
SELECT
  title,
  name,
  COUNT(rental_id) AS rental_count 

FROM film,
     category,
     rental,
     inventory,
     film_category

WHERE film_category.film_id = film.film_id
AND category.category_id = film_category.category_id
AND inventory.film_id = film.film_id
AND rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
AND name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')

GROUP BY name,
         title
ORDER BY name, title ;
```

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: `FROM film JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id JOIN category ON ...`

Comment: The only thing you can do that is worst than using implicit joins, is to mix implicit and explicit joins in the same query.
Change your existing query to only use explicit joins, and never use implicit joins again.

Comment: And of course, the obligatory link to Aaron Bertrand's [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 3):

I personally find it much more readable to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Your query then looks like this:

```sql
SELECT title, name, COUNT(rental_id) AS rental_count 
FROM film
INNER JOIN inventory ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
INNER JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
INNER JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
WHERE name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')
GROUP BY name, title
ORDER BY name, title
;
``
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) clauses to combine tables, e.g.:

```
SELECT title
  , name
  , COUNT(rental_id) AS rental_count 
FROM film
JOIN film_category
  ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
JOIN category
  ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
JOIN inventory
  ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
JOIN rental
  ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
WHERE name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')
GROUP BY name
  , title
ORDER BY name
  , title;
```

Comment: Didn't see your answer before publishing mine. Since it's basically the same code and it seems like you need the reputation points more than me, I've converted mine to a comment and upvoted yours. Cheers.